# ENOENT, stat error while using sendFile

Tags: node.js

I am using `sendFile` option to view the uploaded file. I used `try` `catch` to handle exception, like if the file is not found, I am showing `file not found` error. In my local system (Windows 10), this code is working but in the server (Linux), it is showing `ENOENT, stat error`. What could be the reason? How to fix it?

```
router.get('/api/attachments/:application/:filename', function(request, response) {
  if (!request.isAuthenticated()) {
    response.status(500).json({'ERR':'You are not authenticated. Please log in to continue.'})
    return
  }
  getFile(request.params.application, request.params.filename, function(err, path) {
    try{
      return response.sendFile(path)
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      return response.status(404).json({'ERR':'Document not available', 'Exception':e});
    }
  })
})
```

Kindly help.

Comment: `ENOENT` means "Error NO ENTry", and means that the path (or part of it) could not be found. Is the file where you expect it to be? If you try to use an absolute path does it work then? Oh, and if you're in a hurry then stackoverflow.com is hardly the right forum.

Comment: Error messages are different across operating systems.